# Having Trouble With Completion Handlers and Closures in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, closures, completionhandler

**Background**

The function below calls two functions, which both access an API, retrieve JSON data, parse through it, etc, and then take that data and populates the values of an object variable in my View Controller class.

```
func requestWordFromOxfordAPI(word: String, completion: (_ success: Bool) -> Void) {
        oxfordAPIManager.fetchDictData(word: word)
        oxfordAPIManager.fetchThesData(word: word)

        completion(true)
    }
```

Normally, if there was only one function fetching data, and I wanted to call a new function that takes in the data results and does something with them, I would use a delegate method and call it within the closure of the data fetching function.

**For Example:**

Here, I fetch data from my firebase database and if retrieving the data is succesful, I call `self.delegate?.populateWordDataFromFB(result: combinedModel)`. Since closures occur on separate thread, this ensures that the populateWordDataFromFB function runs only once retrieving the data has finished. Please correct me if I am wrong. I have just recently learned this and am still trying to see the whole picture.

```
    func readData(word: String) {

        let docRef = db.collection(K.FBConstants.dictionaryCollectionName).document(word)

        docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            let result = Result {
                try document.flatMap {
                    try $0.data(as: CombinedModel.self)
                }
            }
            switch result {
            case .success(let combinedModel):
                if let combinedModel = combinedModel {
                    self.delegate?.populateWordDataFromFB(result: combinedModel)
                } else {
                    self.delegate?.fbDidFailWithError(error: nil, summary: "\(word) not found, requesting from OxfordAPI")
                    self.delegate?.requestWordFromOxfordAPI(word: word, completion: { (success) in
                        if success {
                            self.delegate?.populateWordDataFromOX()
                        } else {print("error with completion handler")}
                    })
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                self.delegate?.fbDidFailWithError(error: error, summary: "Error decoding CombinedModel")
            }
        }
    }
```

Also notice from the above code that if the data is not in firebase, I call the delegate method below, which is where I am running into my issue.

```
self.delegate?.requestWordFromOxfordAPI(word: word, completion: { (success) in
                        if success {
                            self.delegate?.populateWordDataFromOX()
                        } else {print("error with completion handler")}
                    })
```

**My Issue**

What I am struggling with is the fact that the `oxfordAPIManager.fetchDictData(word: word)` and `oxfordAPIManager.fetchThesData(word: word)` functions both have closures.

The body of these functions look like this:

```
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.addValue(K.APISettings.acceptField, forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
            request.addValue(K.APISettings.paidAppID , forHTTPHeaderField: "app_id")
            request.addValue(K.APISettings.paidAppKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "app_key")

            let session = URLSession.shared
            _ = session.dataTask(with:request) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    self.delegate?.apiDidFailWithError(error: error, summary: "Error performing task:")
                    return
                }

                if let safeData = data {
                    if let thesaurusModel = self.parseThesJSON(safeData) {
                        self.delegate?.populateThesData(thesModel: thesaurusModel, word: word)
                    }
                }
            }
            .resume()
        }  else {print("Error creating thesaurus request")}
```

I assume both of these functions are running on separate threads in the background. My goal is to call another function once both the `oxfordAPIManager.fetchDictData(word: word)` and `oxfordAPIManager.fetchThesData(word: word)` functions run. These two functions will populate the values of an object variable in my view controller which I will use in the new function. I don't want the new function to be called before the object variable in the view controller is populated with the right data so I tried to implement a completion handler. The completion handler function is being called **BEFORE** the two functions terminate, so when the new function tries to access the object variable in the View Controller, it's empty.

This is my first time trying to implement a completion handler and I tried to follow some other stack overflow posts but was unsuccessful. Also if this is the wrong approach let me know too, please. Sorry for the long explanation and thank you for any input.

Comment: I think like you've implemented `requestWordFromOxfordAPI` wrongly. Is your question asking how to implement it correctly? Can you change `oxfordAPIManager.fetchDictData`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`DispatchGroup`** for this,

Example:

Create a `DispatchGroup`,

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
```

Modify the `requestWordFromOxfordAPI(word: completion:)` method to,

```
func requestWordFromOxfordAPI(word: String, completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool) -> Void) {
    fetchDictData(word: "")
    fetchThesData(word: "")
    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        //code after both methods are executed
        print("Both methods executed")
        completion(true)
    }
}
```

Call `enter()` and `leave()` methods of `DispatchGroup` at the relevant places in `fetchDictData(word:)` and `fetchThesData(word:)` methods.

```
func fetchDictData(word: String) {
    group.enter()
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        //your code
        group.leave()
    }.resume()
}

func fetchThesData(word: String) {
    group.enter()
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        //your code
        group.leave()
    }.resume()
}
```

At last call `requestWordFromOxfordAPI(word: completion:)`

```
requestWordFromOxfordAPI(word: "") { (success) in
    print(success)
}
```